# VBA in Word 2010: how do I fix the relative position of a TextBox?

Tags: vba, textbox, position, ms-word

Writing VBA in Microsoft Word 2010 (no-one's favourite job).  I'm trying to fix the vertical position of a textbox to a location in the document, so that as text is added before, the text box retains its relative position (i.e. moves down if text is inserted before the location it's linked to).

My code is

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 372, 400, 120, 120).Select

With Selection
    .ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Select
    .Collapse
    .TypeText Text:="Text box placement test"

    With .ShapeRange
        .Select
        .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionColumn
        .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
...
```

The key I think is this last property, RelativeVerticalPosition.

I have tried changing it to wdRelativeVerticalPositionLine: this works for the first paragraph (i.e. the text box is fixed to the position in text, so if text is added before it moves correctly): however, for the second and later paragraphs the vertical position is completely wrong.

I have tried changing the LockAnchor property but that makes no change.

The frustration is that this can be done manually (Page layout, Arrange group, Wrap text, more layout options, position, move object with text = checked) but Word won't let me record a macro where I change a textbox's properties, so I can't find the combination of settings to make it work.

Any suggestions?  Or is this just one of the consequences of using 20+ year old code?

Comment: I've checked your problem with `.RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionLine` and it's working fine whichever paragraph I put the shape. I had some text in Document, run your macro, than separately set it to `...PositionLine` and it works. One additional tip- try to remove completely both `.Relative...Position` properties from you macro which should also give a good results.

Comment: Thanks for looking KazJaw.  No - it definitely doesn't work, either with the .Relative....Line or with nothing, presumably because of some other setting I have.  Paragraph 1 works fine, but each paragraph after adds a downwards offset of about 6 cm, so if I could count the paragraph I'm in I could offset this as a work-around.  Any ideas how to find the paragraph number on a page?  Thanks

Comment: It is rather complicated and can result with unexpected behaviour depending of text and object you have in your document. If I have plain text this is a way to select 3rd paragraph on 3rd page: `ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages(3).Rectangles(1).Range.Paragraphs(3).Range.Select` If any error occurs then you need to experiment with the code on your own.

Answer (score 0):

First, you've got to set RelativeVerticalPosition as well. 
Second, be careful with using .ShapeRange. Incorrent usage of .ShapeRange may be the problem in some cases.
That's a small snippet from my code. Just tested it with Word 2010.

```
Dim oShp As Shape
Set oShp = Selection.ShapeRange(1)
oShp.RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionColumn
oShp.RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionLine
```

So if your "move object with text" is unchecked, it'll become checked after running the code.